# What is the difference MPI vs OpenMP?

Tags: mpi

I just want to know the differences between MPI vs OpenMP for a school project I have.
I'm new on Ubuntu and i can't find a trustworthy website. I tried so many now. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

This is a [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) type of question. Since you don't know and it's for a school project, I can safely say you'll want OpenMP (assuming you wanted to know the difference to know which one to use). That being said, the biggest difference that comes to mind is that MPI was designed for distributed memory systems (like clusters) and OpenMP was designed for shared memory systems (like your PC).

Answer (score 0):

Even if not aimed specifically to OpenMP vs. MPI, I think that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185444/why-is-mpi-considered-harder-than-shared-memory-and-erlang-considered-easier-wh) answers to a good portion of your question. To be really brief, MPI is not a shared memory model and is targeted to very highly parallelized systems. OpenMP is a shared memory model (as simple pthreads) and one of its advantages is that the parallelization process is easier with respect to MPI. So it's harder to convert a serial program into a MPI parallelized version, but if you'd plan to run the program on thousands of nodes, you'll probably have better performance with MPI.

As a side note, I think that you posted on the wrong site. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is best suited for this kind of questions.